# Display VDO OpenCV tkinter Python, Face Mask Detection

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, display

I gets stuck on this code for a while. I can only make the Camera blink but doesnt pop up GUI with VDO and also get this Error "None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)". I have no Clue how to solve this. I did try to writethem with OOP but still get the same issue.

Here is my code..............

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import datetime

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


mainFrame = Tk()
app = Frame(mainFrame, bg="white")
mainFrame.title('Face Mask Detector')

app.grid()
# Create a label in the frame
lmain = Label(app)
lmain.grid()

protopath = "face_detector/deploy.prototxt"
modelpath = "face_detector/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt=protopath, caffeModel=modelpath)

mask_detector = load_model('face_mask.model')
# Capture from camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def video_stream():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(1, video_stream)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300), (104, 177, 123))

    detector.setInput(blob)
    detections = detector.forward()

    faces = []
    bbox = []
    results = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > 0.5:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)
            face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

            faces.append(face)
            bbox.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    if len(faces) > 0:
        results = mask_detector.predict(faces)

    for (face_box, results) in zip(bbox, results):
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = face_box
        (WithoutMask,SurgicalMask,ClothMask) = results


        if (ClothMask > WithoutMask and ClothMask > SurgicalMask):
            label = "Cloth Mask"
        elif (WithoutMask > SurgicalMask and WithoutMask > ClothMask):
            label = "Without Mask"
        else:
            label = "SurgicalMask"

        if label == "Cloth Mask":
            color = (0, 255, 0)
        elif label == "Without Mask":
            color = (0, 0, 255)
        else:
            color = (255, 0, 0)

        # include the probability in the label
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(WithoutMask, ClothMask, SurgicalMask) * 100)

            # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
            # frame
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

        

#Build Button Widget
btnClose = ttk.Button(mainFrame, text = 'Close',width = 10)
#Button Widget position
btnClose.grid(sticky='S',pady =10)
#Command Button
btnClose.configure(command= lambda: mainFrame.destroy())

video_stream()
mainFrame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying the video and you are not waiting to give the video time to display. Your missing:

```
cv2.imshow('video', img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

full example to try:

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This should help you to figure out what your missing.

Answer (score 0):

I used to  have this part at the end but i did remove them because the VDO still not show Tkinter GUI.

```
                cv2.imshow("Application", frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('q'):
                    break
```